# how to install Ubuntu over http in virt-manager

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, installation, http, virtual-machines

I am having a situation where I can not use a CD or PxE boot or wubi to install.I need to necessarily do an http install of Ubuntu.I am basically trying to create a guest OS in
a virtualization setup on Xen on a non VT hardware.On a non VT hardware the virt-manager does not allow to install from local ISO or PXE even the only option is via a URL on http://

Here is what I did
1) Download ubuntu 10.04 32 bit ISO
2) Kept it in /var/www (apache2 is running)
3) renamed it to ubuntu.iso

and when I reached a stage where installation begins I gave path 
http://localhost/ubuntu.iso
but I got an error `any installable distribution not found.`

4) After this I did

```
mkdir /var/www/sk

mount -t iso9660 /var/www/ubuntu.iso /var/www/sk -o loop
```

and this time during the installation I gave path http://localhost/sk
I was able to see the contents in browser http://localhost/sk which you will see in a normal CD.
But beginning installation I got same error

```
ValueError: Could not find an installable distribution at 'http://localhost/sk
```

So I want to just confirm if http install is done only this way or some other way because the installation is not proceeding.

Comment: How did you "reached a stage where installation begins"? What are you booting from?

Comment: @scirus virt-manager asks me from where you want to install and then 
 shows three option 
1) CD or local ISO this is greyed out
2) http install (only this is working)
3) PXE install (this is also greyed out)

So selecting 2 I move ahead and then give url http://localhost/wk it does not boot neither the installation begins.